# Student name alone with DOJ and duration

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TJLK.png)Write a query to display the student's first name, date of joining and completing date of each course. Give alias name for completion date as DOC. Sort the result based on student's first name, Date of joining and Date of Completion.

[Note: Completion Date can be calculated using DOJ and duration]

Comment: If this is a homework, then show us what have you tried so far? Also, post the create and insert statements to set up basic data.

Comment: I have tried the doj+duration.The duration in the course table are like 6,2,4,5 if I execute the above program the result shows like  doj as 10-mar-18 and doc as 14-mar-18 which is incorrect I want answer like doj as 10-mar-18 and doc as 10-may-18.  The difference is calculated in days but I want it in months .i even tried to multiple duration with 30 it still show error when month like june,July are involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select s.first_name,
  c.course_name,
  s.doj, 
  add_months(s.doj, c.duration) as doc
from student s join course c on s.student_id = c.student_id
order by first_name, doj, doc
```

Comment: The problem is there are more than 6 courses and each have different duration of period

Comment: That might be true, but - I don't know which tables you have, the way they are related to each other, etc., so I posted what I *thought* might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The duration in the course table are like 6,2,4,5 if I execute the above program the result shows like  doj as 10-mar-18 and doc as 14-mar-18 which is incorrect I want answer like doj as 10-mar-18 and doc as 10-may-18.  The difference is calculated in days but I want it in months .i even tried to multiple duration with 30 it still show error when month like june,July are involved

Comment: If duration is in months, then use ADD_MONTHS function. See modified query.

Comment: And  please, please PLEASE _PLEASE_ ..... _ALWAYS_ use 4-digit years.  I realize you are a student and possibly not even born then, but does the term Y2K mean nothing to you?